# How to regularly switching between two html divs using animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have html code with two divs containig tables with informations about departures and arrivals of airplanes as shown below. Second table is under first table but it is too big for screen and I need it to be displaying on the screen without scrolling. So I need to display just one table and switching between tables in regularly intervals (for example 30 seconds) using CSS animation or javascript. 
Can anyone help me please?

CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body {
        background-image: url("kosiceBackground.jpg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: 1920px 1080px;
    <!-- Neskor bude treba nastavit backgroung-size na 1920*1080  -->
    }

    h1 {
        color: #3900ff;
        text-align: center;
    }
    h4 {
        color: #000000;
        text-align: center;
    }
    h5 {
        color: #ff0712;
        text-align: center;
    }

    p {
        font-family: verdana;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    span {
        color: #3900ff;
    }

    .table{
        background-color: #3b3b3b !important;
        /* border: 1px solid black !important;*/
        opacity:0.8 !important;
        color: whitesmoke !important;
        border-radius: 20px;
    }

    .table td, .table th{
        border-top: 1px solid black !important;
        /*  border-bottom: 1px solid black;*/

    }

    .table tr:first-child, .table th:first-child {
        border-top: none !important;
    }
</style>
```

Html:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
<div>
    <div class="container" style="margin:50px">
        <div class="row text-center"><h1 style="text-align: center; color: whitesmoke;">Departures</h1></div>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead >
            <tr >
                <th style="border-top: none !important;">Airline</th>
                <th style="border-top: none !important;">Estimated time</th>
                <th style="border-top: none !important;">Scheduled time</th>
                <th style="border-top: none !important;">Flight number</th>
                <th style="border-top: none !important;">Status</th>
                <th style="border-top: none !important;">Gate</th>
                <th style="border-top: none !important;">To</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            <c:forEach var="departure" items="${departuresArrivals.departures}">
                <tr id="dep">
                    <td>${departure.airline}</td>
                    <td>${departure.estimated}</td>
                    <td>${departure.scheduled}</td>
                    <td>${departure.flightNumber}</td>
                    <td>${departure.status}</td>
                    <td>${departure.gate}</td>
                    <td>${departure.to}</td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
            <tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="container" style="margin:50px">
        <div class="row text-center"><h1 style="text-align: center; color: whitesmoke;">Arrivals</h1></div>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="border-top: none !important;">Airline</th>
                <th style="border-top: none !important;">Estimated time</th>
                <th style="border-top: none !important;">Scheduled time</th>
                <th style="border-top: none !important;">Flight number</th>
                <th style="border-top: none !important;">Status</th>
                <th style="border-top: none !important;">From</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            <c:forEach var="arrival" items="${departuresArrivals.arrivals}">
                <tr>
                    <td>${arrival.airline}</td>
                    <td>${arrival.estimated}</td>
                    <td>${arrival.scheduled}</td>
                    <td>${arrival.flightNumber}</td>
                    <td>${arrival.status}</td>
                    <td>${arrival.from}</td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
            <tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Divs with tables have class=container.

Comment: `<marquee><table>....</table></marquee>`

Comment: Please clarify which 2 tables you need to switch between. Also please post your CSS file(s) if any. It is useful if you create a code-snippet so we see the current status  of your attempts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript AJAX to make it more restful. You can write functions called using buttons and switch between two `<div>` elements using those functions.

Comment: It is information screen for visitors so I need switching it automatically without clicking on buttons.